# Does a Bar Chart Show Statistical Significance?

Tags: statistics, chi-squared, anova

Given a picture bar chart with no other data, means or standard deviation. If one bar is higher than the rest can you prove that it is statistically significant?

What kind of test would you perform?

Comment: You are correct to be suspicious of poorly labeled bar charts as a way to decide whether categories are equally likely. // A test of proportions, `prop.test` in R or a chi-squared test for equal proportions would give more reliable results. See my Answer for examples.

Answer (score 0, accepted):

Bar charts that give only proportions or percentages for
various categories are of almost no value in deciding whether
categories are equally likely. One must know the *counts*
in each category (or be able to reconstruct counts from the
total sample size) in order to test whether categories are equally likely.

'Error bars' on the bars might sometimes be useful, but
there seems to be no standard way to make them--much less consistently useful information how to interpret error bars. Nothing is better than for a bar plot to show *counts* along with
total sample size. Then rely on a formal
statistical test to assess equality of categories.

*Examples:* Suppose I am rolling a die to see if it is fair.
After some exploratory rolls I get percentages
for each face as follows, and make a bar chart
showing the *counts.*

```
Faces:  1  2  3  4  5  6 
Pct:   12 14 16 12 26 20
```

The bar for `5`'s stands out as being higher
than the rest.

[image]

However, this is not necessarily
'proof' of an unfair die. Suppose, the percentage
results are based on counts below for only $n=50$ rolls
of the die.

```
 Faces:   1  2  3  4  5  6 
 Counts:  6  7  8  6 13 10
```

A test for equal proportions in R shows P-value $0.37 > 0.05 = 5\%,$
which is far from a statistically significant result. It would be wrong
to declare the die unfair.

```
prop.test(c(6,7,8,6,13,10), rep(50, 6))

    6-sample test for equality of proportions 
    without continuity correction

data:  c(6, 7, 8, 6, 13, 10) out of rep(50, 6)
X-squared = 5.376, df = 5, p-value = 0.3717
alternative hypothesis: two.sided
sample estimates:
prop 1 prop 2 prop 3 prop 4 prop 5 prop 6 
  0.12   0.14   0.16   0.12   0.26   0.20
```

By contrast, suppose I roll the die $n=600$ times and get the following
counts.

```
Faces:    1   2   3   4   5   6
counts:  66  84  91 112 103 144
```

Percentages rounded to one decimal place are as shown below,

```
Faces:     1    2    3    4    6    6
Pct:    11.0 14.0 15.2 18.7 17.2 24.0
```

A bar chart of frequencies may look somewhat similar to the one above in its 'irregularities'.

[image]

However, with 600 rolls we have a lot more information. For
these counts, `prop.test` gives a P-value near $0,$ indicating
that it would be almost impossible for a truly fair die to give such counts.

```
prop.test(tabulate(y),rep(600,6))

    6-sample test for equality of proportions 
    without continuity correction

data:  tabulate(y) out of rep(600, 6)
X-squared = 42.984, df = 5, p-value = 3.723e-08
alternative hypothesis: two.sided
sample estimates:
   prop 1    prop 2    prop 3    prop 4    prop 5    prop 6 
0.1100000 0.1400000 0.1516667 0.1866667 0.1716667 0.2400000
```

*Note:* Here is the R code for the 50 rolls
of a fair die and the 600 rolls of an unfair die used as examples above:

```
set.seed(507)
x = sample(1:6, 50, rep=T)

set.seed(2021)
y = sample(1:6, 600, rep=T, p = c(2,3,3,3,3,4))
```